# Using extra CPU time in ESXI for scientific computing

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have an ESXI environment that normally only uses 10-25% of its CPU power.  Is it possible to create a VM and allow it to use all of the extra CPU power?  If another VM started using more, I would want the extra computation VM to throttle so the performance of critical VM's would not be affected.

ESXI Version 6.0.0

Comment: What you're after is the default behaviour of ESXi - just create your new VM, give it 95% of the memory and CPU cores of the actual host and let ESXi sort the rest out.

Comment: But how do I not have it impact the other more important VM's?

Answer (score 4):

You could use resource pools to reduce the priority of the idle VMs. The idle group can have CPU shares set to low. Add VMs to the idle pool, each with vCPU set to the number of cores per socket, until the load is what you want.

Further, DRS and/or DPM can consolidate workloads on hosts. Although if you are licensed for all that, you also can have DPM just vacate and shut down idle hosts.